# Viz.js failing to render DOT to SVG in production build

Tags: svg, graphviz, elm, production-environment, dev-to-production

I am building a webapp that dynamically renders [Argdown](https://argdown.org/) argument maps. The Argdown engine converts a string to a Graphviz DOT graph to an SVG, relying on the synchronous-JS version of [Viz.js](https://github.com/aduh95/viz.js) for the conversion. The application works as intended in development mode, but produces an incorrect SVG in production.

Development:

[image]

Production:

[image]

In particular, the `Argdown.ArgdownApplication.run()` method using the `"export-web-component"` process produces identical output in dev and prod at every step except for the `svg` itself. Argdown (incorrectly?) does not export the `SyncDotToSvgExportPlugin` plugin required for the SVG generation step, so I am requiring Viz.js directly and defining the plugin in my project, based entirely on the one in the Argdown source.

What could cause Viz.js to produce this varying output?

The app is written in Elm, using ports to communicate between the JS-managed map generation and the rest of the app. It uses create-elm-app's `elm-app build` to compile the source into the production bundle. Elm's webpack config is [available](https://github.com/halfzebra/create-elm-app/blob/0e60539d139e731495ef231c966ddf4d0631b83b/config/webpack.config.prod.js), but it's unclear if it is overrideable if the issue turns out to be there. JS dependencies are managed using Yarn.

Versions:

- Node: 12.20.0
- Yarn packages

  - @aduh95/viz.js: 3.2.1
  - @argdown/core: 1.5.0
  - @argdown/node: 1.5.3
- Elm: 0.19.1
- create-elm-app: 5.21.0